# android studio 3.0 | AAPT2 Error: failed to execute apt

Tags: android

when building an app with some videos (mp4) inside raw/ directory i get this error:

```
raw_frenulectomia.mp4.flat: error: failed to read data meta data.
error: failed parsing overlays.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
 com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for 
 details
```

with previous version, everything compiled allright. any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aapt2 is enabled by default when you use android plugin for gradle 3.0.

This is to

> improve incremental resource processing

as stated here.

But if you are facing issues with it, you can switch back to previous version by adding this in gradle.properties

android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: It's my pleasure

Comment: Please always state and give credit to your [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail).