# Exception : AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Task :processDebugResources Failed to execute aapt com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor200.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 47 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2$$Lambda$489/579799618.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
```

Where will the `AAPT2` logs be saved? 
While migrating to `gradle-plugin-3.0.0`, I am getting this exception.

Comment: The errors should be just above the stacktrace. If you're running from Android Studio you can find the full log in the Gradle Log window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941174/8818381 ***Akhilesh Awasthi*** answer was correct for me. I've examine my xml file and find out that in one of TextView I've set `android:layout_height="20"` without `'dp'`. Don't know why, but in *Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6* if you edit in Designer tool your UI units didn't add in xml. This may be bug of Canary version.
Try to carefully examine all elements in your recently edited xmls

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I ran into this very issue today morning and found the solution for it too. This issue is created when you have messed up one of your .xml files. I'll suggest you go through them one by one and look for recent changes made. It might be caused by a silly mistake.

In my case, I accidentally hardcoded a color string as #FFFFF(Bad practice, I know). As you can see it had 5 F instead of 6. It didn't show any warning but was the root of the same issue as encountered by you.

Edit 1: Another thing you can do is to run **assembleDebug** in your gradle console. It will find the specific line for you.

Edit 2: Adding an image for reference to run **assembleDebug**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i almost get crazy with this silly bug. In my case was style="@style/?android:attr/progressBarStyle"

The editor added the (@style/) before the style.

Answer (score 38):

## AAPT2 Error solution.

If your Android studio has been updated.

Maybe, you would face an error in the studio like "**AAPT 2 error: check the log for details**"

This error will occur when you have done something wrong in your .xml file such as incorrect value, content not found, etc.

But, At that time you will not have the error specification there. Because the new version of Android Studio does not give you a specific error. It gives like AAPT2 error.

If you want to know where the actual error is then

### Follow step.

> 1. **Look at the panel which is at the right of your Android studio Check out the "Gradle" tab and click on it.**
> 2. **You will see the "app" option. Click on it.**
> 3. **In the app options you will see [Tasks -> build] click on it.**
> 4. **Then you will get options list and see "assembleDebug" double click on it.**
> 5. **Keep the patience and See build tab at the bottom panel of Android studios, you will get an exact error there what you made a mistake in which file and which position.**

[image: Click on assembleDebug and see log you can get the actual error is where]

Comment: Thank you dude..actually I has been looking for this quick solution from so many days

Answer (score 12):

The error might be cause by non-ASCII symbols in gradle path. E.g. cyrillic symbols of the user folder. So, the problem is solved just by switching to another directory with ASCII-only path.

[image: Troublesome gradle path]

Comment: How did you find that? This is ridiculous.

Comment: @Sergio just because I faced the problem: as many cyrillic-reading users I had a Windows user named in cyrillic alphabet. A default gradle folder was placed inside a user folder, so, an error occured.

Comment: I have a user folder with accented vowels in Portuguese, and I was getting this AAPT error. Bould never tell it was about gradle folder.

Answer (score 8):

Just add this line as per your compileSdkVersion

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

[image: Update Build Tools Version]

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem with a png file maybe, look here :

> 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2
>   error: check logs for details
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)

It can be corrupted image or jpeg image with png extension

Comment: this actually save me. I had used an image generator that made some 9 patch images and copied those into place. that cause this similar error that had absolutely no other indication that it was an image causing the issue.  and assembleDebug provided no other indication of error.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the ERROR with three steps 
1. I checked for the problem SOURCE 
2. Provided the correct string/text, because it was the CAUSE 
3. I cleaned the project, you ll see it under BUILD.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check the latest edited XML file. It is the main Villian
I had once such error, I then checked the last xml file, ther was a line like     `android:layout_marginTop="."` 
I changed it to `android:layout_marginTop="16dp"`.
That fixed the bug!

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem. [Akilesh awasthi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941174/5106406) answer helped me fix it. My problem was a little different. I was using **places_ic_search** icon **from com.google.android.gms:play-services-location** The latest version **com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0** does not provide the icon places_ic_search. Because of this there was a problem in the layout.xml files.That led to build failure **AAPT2 error: check logs for details** as the message. Android studio should be showing cannot find drawable places_ic_search as the message instead.

I ended up using a lower version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-location temporarily. Hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 3):

I made a stupid mistake. In my case, I made the project path too deep. Like this: `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Intsig_Android_BCRSDK_AndAS_V1.11.18_20180719\Intsig_Android_BCRScanSDK_AndAS_V1.10.1.20180711\project\as\AS_BcrScanCallerSvn2`

Please migrate the project to the correct workspace. 
Hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error only when you are generating signed Apk . Then the problem might be in one or more of the imported media file format.
I have used an image directly from net to studio and was not able to generate sign apk, then found the error .

> from Gradle >assembleRelease
>   then got the error in console.
>   see the error log in console image.
>   [image: This was my Error, See its clearly written that one of my image format is not valid or unknown]

Answer (score 3):

Ensure if no image in drawable folder is corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I tried every possible solution to fix this frustrating error and only below worked for me. 
In your build.gradle add this:

```
android {
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case above solution did not work.
In my case , Bitdefender Antivirus was Preventing  AAPT2 from making change on certain file.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I got this error while working on some Udacity projects.
I fixed it by adding the following code to the top-level build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase()
    if (osName.contains("windows")) {
        buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking a way to get to the heart of the issue. Android studio contains a feature within the edit configurations panel that simplifies this possible. By clicking on the "app" tag (It is typically to the left of the top run button)

You will open the option to edit configurations. From there create an instance of the gradle option to yourself.

The core features are actually the gradle project as well as the task. Connect the task to your debug initiative.

When you run your app through this setting, Android will spit out detailed errors(That we all wish would appear more often) and these errros will point directly a what needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and no meaningful message to tell me what was wrong.
I finally removed this line from gradle.properties and got a meaningful error message.

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

In my case somebody on the team had changed a **.jpg** extension to a **.png** and the file header didn't match the extension. *Fun.*

Answer (score 0):

`style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"`

to

`style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"`

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error because of using `&` character  directly in layout xml.
So, please be careful about using html entities in your project.

Answer (score 0):

someone might get some help from my case
I just put a hard coded color hex value without `#` like this by mistake `android:textColor="FFA500"` almost made me mad to findout. `#FFA500` this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your logs :

> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       ... 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
>       at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

I feel some PNG files are corrupted and were not parsed. Sometimes the images have an extension but are not real PNG.

You can check if the images in your project are real PNGs with the below command :

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -I {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'
```

After getting the list use [this](https://www.online-convert.com/) site to convert them to PNG. Then check your build again.

Answer (score 0):

this problem mostly about related xml typo mistakes, for me i just changed

```
       <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="@string/str_search"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
```

android:background="null"

to

android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding Error example (Error in xml attribute):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     //<-- Remove this
    android:layout_height="match_parent" //<-- Remove this
>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had:

```
<string-array name="gilan">
   <item>Sowme'eh Sara</item>
</string-array>
```

and i'd changed it to:

```
<string-array name="gilan">
   <item>Sowme`eh Sara</item>
</string-array>
```

actually `'` character was the problem and i'd changed it to **`** (Backtick) character.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally added to the last XML file that I was working on the encoding attribute **Twice**.
i.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!--Remove this duplicate declaration!-->
.....
Rest of XML
.....
```

I strongly suggest checking if this is the cause since it took me quite a while to get over it because Android Studio can not point where is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

possible issue related to this can be with your XML files. I have faced this when I deleted my unnecery xml files.

For remedy from this error in gradle.properties of the module, add this below line:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

after adding this line, restart the gradle.

and do once clean, rebuild your project.

Comment: `android.enableAapt2=false` is deprecated, and will be removed by the end of 2018, so this doesn't solve the problem, is just a temporary workaround.

Answer (score -1):

This resolved the issue for me...
Build|Clean project 
Refactor|Remove unused resources
I am still a beginner at this so I cannot explain why this might have worked. It was an arbitrary choice on my part; it was simple, did not require detailed changes and I just thought it might help :)

Answer (score -3):

some symbols should be transferred like '%'

```
<string name="test" formatted="false">95%</string>
```