# Android Studio can't build a fresh Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Iam completly new to Android Studio. I did a fresh installation, but i cant even build a fresh Project. Java RE and JDK are also installed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

it fails to find a bunch of files( a lot more to be exact):

```
C:\Users\Kevin Me?mer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\772b859d9774811adda23f9733ce921e\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_half_black_48dp.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\Kevin Me?mer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\772b859d9774811adda23f9733ce921e\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\Kevin Me?mer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\772b859d9774811adda23f9733ce921e\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png: error: file not found.
```

Did i missed something? I also reinstalled Android Studio on different paths, but that didnt fixed anything.

Here is the Build Gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is the Build Gradle Modul:app

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kevinmemer.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.1'
 }
```

Here is additionally my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you gone through this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589873/aapt2-error-check-logs-for-details?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: show you xml file

Comment: i added the xml file

Comment: Not manifest file......activity xml

Comment: Did you try to clean build? Did you try Invalidate Caches and Restart?

Comment: clean build doesnt work aswell. Invalidate caches will get adressed also with it isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a non-ascii character in your username, which is causing the file path to contain that as well. AAPT2 currently has trouble parsing non-ascii characters on windows.

There's an experimental flag you could use if you try the newest Android Studio 3.2 alphas: you can add `android.useAapt2FromMaven=true` in your gradle.properties file. This will work only in the *newest* android gradle plugin (3.2 alpha 9 or newer), so you need to update your android studio *and* android gradle plugin version.