# Gradle build :app:mergeDebugResources file not found error

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I installed a fresh copy of the newest Android Studio and then created a new "Basic Activity" project with the default settings. Now when I try to execute Gradle *Build* it will generate several "file not found" errors as follows:

```
16:49:27: Executing task 'build'...

Executing tasks: [build]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\anim\abc_tooltip_exit.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.0.aar\6a74caf0abf591df5d9a1f94023d971c\res\layout\design_navigation_item.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable\abc_btn_colored_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\layout\abc_action_bar_up_container.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\layout\abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_right_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\color\abc_secondary_text_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable\abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\color\abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\layout\abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\color\abc_primary_text_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_left_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_black_36dp.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-27.1.0.aar\18f801487329cf88fc1bb34c25ff9eeb\res\layout\notification_template_lines_media.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.0.aar\6a74caf0abf591df5d9a1f94023d971c\res\drawable-v21\avd_show_password.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.0.aar\6a74caf0abf591df5d9a1f94023d971c\res\drawable\design_password_eye.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\anim\abc_fade_in.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\color-v23\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.0.aar\6a74caf0abf591df5d9a1f94023d971c\res\anim\design_snackbar_out.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\K?ytt?j?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\adf488ceb29f037c73824725aff44f25\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
9 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 1 up-to-date
16:49:32: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

Any idea why those files are missing ?
Could it be the path name because my username is "Käyttäjä" and for some reason the compiler cannot handle it ?
How to solve the situation ?

It looks like the files are in place for example:

[image]

Comment: It's a bug in AAPT2, which has been fixed in the *newest* alpha version. Please see my explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49757422/8856784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It was the path name thing. What I did was I created a new Windows 10 user with no special characters in the name and now it works just fine. This sounds like a bug. Reported.

Comment: btw. Izabela's comment has the better solution before the next official resolution.