# Android build fails on Bamboo with Aapt2Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, bamboo

I keep getting this from Bamboo.
Tried all solutions mentioned. Nothing works for me yet

like this: [Gradle build :app:mergeDebugResources file not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694622/gradle-build-appmergedebugresources-file-not-found-error)

> :app:mergeIt2Resources
>   09-May-2018 21:00:33    C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\8bd8dfdd2cf63cd839f54537b3cca1ce\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:33    C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-0.9.6.0.aar\0db248fe8779d2711cac6d6677bfeb28\res\anim\popup_exit.xml: error: file not found.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:33    C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-0.9.6.0.aar\0db248fe8779d2711cac6d6677bfeb28\res\drawable-anydpi-v21\md_nav_back.xml: error: file not found.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:33    C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\8bd8dfdd2cf63cd839f54537b3cca1ce\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:33    C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\8bd8dfdd2cf63cd839f54537b3cca1ce\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:33    C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\ab46dfcb77975b5f25129199a474e726\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
>   
>   `.
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .`
>   C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-0.9.6.0.aar\0db248fe8779d2711cac6d6677bfeb28\res\layout-ldrtl-v17\md_listitem_singlechoice.xml: error: file not found.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:42    Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    :app:mergeIt2Resources FAILED
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    * What went wrong:
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeIt2Resources'.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    * Try:
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44
>   09-May-2018 21:00:44    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in AAPT2 with non-ascii characters in file-paths on Windows. Update to android gradle plugin version 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer where this is fixed.

Comment: Still getting the error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeIt2Resources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\525d312999e542d9a8a4472bd9651209\res\layout\abc_action_bar_up_container.xml: error: file not found.

Comment: Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha13-4662957-windows.jar\9fd6c5e1bafb02ba1525472293a7817e\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha13-4662957-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          C:\work\bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\DDLP-DD-JOB1\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\it2 \
          C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\525d312999e542d9a8a4472bd9651209\res\layout\abc_action_bar_up_container.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha13-4662957-windows Daemon #5

Comment: That is very weird. Can you delete the C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\ directory and try again?