# Gradle build failed after update to 3.2.0

Tags: android, gradle

So after update to Gradle plugin to 3.2.0 and gradle-wrapper to 4.6 I facing with issue. Android Studio version is 3.2 Using Gradle + version which is alpha 11 also no result.

What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

I also can not run `.gradle bulid --stacktrace` due to company security policy.

And also, I am trying to fully delete SDK folder, but no result.

Comment: Some people said that after they used the Android Studio Canary the issue was solved. However, the solution I used as simply to use gradle 3.1.4.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Android Studio and invalidate Cache? I also updated everything to 3.2.0 and I didn't have this problem :/

Comment: @MatPag of course)

Comment: It looks like your company security program might be blocking aapt2 from being executed. Check that program or any anti-viruses you might have.

Comment: I got the solution from below link, you can try once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941174/7218815

Answer (score 0):

I used gradle 3.1.4 and this solved it for me