# Error: failed linking file resources. has any one got the fix?

Tags: java, android

I got a failed linking file resources during the build. Has any one got the fix?

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:512)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:249)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>       ... 32 more
>       Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file processing failed, see logs for details
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.waitForAll(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:121)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:141)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:104)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:293)
>           ... 48 more
>   Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>       at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
>       at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:491)
>       ... 49 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
>       at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
>       ... 51 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:443)
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:395)
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:312)
>       at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

Comment: `Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.`

Comment: That’s a nice stacktrace to dump here. Perhaps consider showing a [mcve]

Comment: perhaps you can also share your build.gradle file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550810/6039129

Comment: problem solved see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was hard coded color resource problem in an xml file. I wrote five hex values for color instead of 6 , and android studio is quite strange for not pointing out the line due to which this error was taking place. found help from this stack overflow link –

[AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589873/aapt2-error-check-logs-for-details)

Answer (score 0):

> Clean Project
>
> Rebuild project
>
> Sync project with gradle file

Comment: thanks for quick response. yes It normally gets solved by doing this but it was hard coded color resource problem in an xml file. I wrote five hex values for color instead of 6 , and android studio is quite strange for not pointing out the line due to which this error was taking place. found help from this link