# AAPT2 gradle issue in android studio 3.0 beta4

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, aapt

[image]**Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details**

We have already added android.enableAapt2=false in gradle.properties file

Comment: Please refer this it's helps you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail/46988596#46988596

Comment: What error are you getting after adding android.enableAapt2=false in your project

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216453/3806413

Answer (score 4):

For me, there was no need to add `android.enableAapt2=false` to my *gradle.properties*. The solution for me was to make sure that in my gradle build file my `compileSdkVersion` is set to 26, `buildToolsVersion` is set to 26.0.2 and `targetSdkVersion` is set to 26.

***Note***: In my build file, I had to do this check for all target and compile sdkVersions including product flavors:

- *mobile*
- *tv*

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is still having issues, i.e loading up demos etc or importing projects. You need to make sure (like everyone else has stated):

You add the following statement to your gradle.properties file

**android.enableAapt2=false**

Now here is for the bit that they should have filled you in on. Chances are if you have imported a project there may not be a gradle.properties file this can be for a wide range of reasons old gradles being used auto fixing issues on build etc.

But seriously, If you can't find it right click in gradle scripts and click on new resource bundle and type gradle. This will create a gradle.properties just paste that code there and run the program. I would not use this as a permanent work around. I stumbled across this whilst importing a project that didn't have a gradle attached to the folder, normally making an app from scratch will have the properties file there.

Comment: Read my comment it's about adding the gradle properties file, which no one has mentioned.

Comment: That means you are answering a wrong question. The OP is not asking how to find the `gradle.properties` or how to create a `gradle.properties` in case if it is not found anywhere.

Comment: quite a toxic little fella aint yah

Comment: Which part is toxic? Please don't interpret my previous comment badly, I am just actually trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it mate finally

please update your compileSdkVersion to 26.That will solve your issue.I think so

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

i have Solved it with increasing compileSDKVersion to 26

Comment: Could you please tell me Android Studio version?

Comment: I have changed compileSDKVersion 26 and buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'. But still facing same issue.

Comment: I have Android studio 3.0.Please remove the android.enableAapt2=false whaich you have added

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by this line being missing from the Gradle dependencies:

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

Answer (score 1):

**For Cordova developers those working on android studio**
I had faced this issue while changing the support library from **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0** to **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1** in order to support the foreground service feature of Android Oreo; to solve this add the following lines of code in **build.gradle** file `

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 27
      }
}
```

After that comment following lines of code in **build.gradle** file. **Most important

```
cdvCompileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
```

Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `gradle.properties` file this line

`android.enableAapt2=false`

EDIT:

You should use stable verison of Android Studio 3

Comment: We have already added `android.enableAapt2=false` in gradle.properties file

Comment: i have already checked with stable version but still facing same issue

Comment: have you solved your issue.I am facing Similar problem just now

Comment: Are you using 9patches?

Comment: @mac229 if you are saying to me , i am not using any 9 patches image. but updated project to Android Studio 3.0 and facing this issue

Comment: We are facing this issue for last 6  hours before that same configuration was running fine. I have added different solutions but not working.

Comment: Even we checked by updating android studio version but still facing same issue with stable version.

Comment: Whats the main issue .I don't get it. @Ramkailash if you got solution ,please mention me also.that  will be great help

Comment: I am using 9patch images. When I want to use 9patch image I am facing this problem.