# Getting issue with Android Release Build Error

Tags: android-studio, react-native, gradle

I created one project using React Native. Every things was working fine until I updated android studio latest version. I am able to create debug apk but getting issue with Release build.

compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tascapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22 
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Add jitpack repository (added by tipsi-stripe)
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting following error. I tried several solutions from internet like cache clean, change buildtool version etc. still no solution.

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:556)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor318.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:827)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:534)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /home/owner/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /home/owner/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/processReleaseManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml -S /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/release/processReleaseResources/r -F /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/release/processReleaseResources/out/resources-release.ap_ -D /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/release/processReleaseResources/manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.tascapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release --no-version-vectors}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:502)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:481)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:83)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:823)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /home/owner/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /home/owner/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/processReleaseManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml -S /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/release/processReleaseResources/r -F /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/release/processReleaseResources/out/resources-release.ap_ -D /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/release/processReleaseResources/manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.tascapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols /var/www/html/projects/ontasc-mobile/dev/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release --no-version-vectors}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1374)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:973)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:821)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:663)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/owner/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:395)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Try to look https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216453/1697583

Comment: I already tried those solution but no luck my Android version is 3.2.1

Comment: put more details about your problem, like your build.gradle, your gradle.wrapper. That is a generic error, is hard to see with only this.

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo I added more details. Please check.

Comment: how are in your android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties?
Look the version, like this:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: And in your android/build.gradle you have 'google()' in your repositore, if not you need to add.

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo yes distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip and google() is also added

Comment: See if you have downloaded SDK 26 and 22.
A workaround is to delete android and ios folders and use 'react-native upgrade' if you want to continue without update by Android Studio.

Comment: try to build it by  changing tagetSdkVersion and compiledSdkVersion to  26

Comment: previously I was using 26 but I was getting same issue with 26 as well. So I downgraded to test