# Gradle not building?

Tags: android

> Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>   Information:Gradle: BUILD FAILED in 8s Information:12/24/2017 11:57 AM
>   - Compilation completed with 5 errors and 0 warnings in 10s 672ms Error:Gradle: failed to create directory
>   'G:\Games\Tester\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\boltz\tester'.
>   Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details Error:Gradle: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2
>   error: check logs for details Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Please take a look at the following this may help you post.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail/46988209 If possible please provide more details like which gradle and studio version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aapt2 is enabled by default when you use android plugin for gradle 3.0.

Try this in gradle.properties :

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Thanks man.. I am a noob at android developing .. this helps a lot

Comment: @BoltZ, my pleasure to help you, friend.