# how to solve layout activity_main not found?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
C:\Users\acer\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:error: attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' not found.
Error:error: attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' not found.
Error:error: attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' not found.
Error:error: attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.example.acer.myapplication:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' not found.
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Comment: Post your layout code for the main activity this is where the problem is occuring

Comment: it is in the main activity

Comment: Can you post the code for your main activity and that activites xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.acer.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
         />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the maven.google.com repository declared in your module-level build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

Add the library as a dependency in the same build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: can you please explaine

Comment: Open your module level build.gradle and check if dependency for constraint layout is added

Comment: Just as ヅ fix said, you're missing a dependency on the constraint layout. Edit your app/build.gradle to contain these lines.