# Android Studio Collaboration Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

So, me and my friend are trying to collaborate on an app, but when he transfers the code to my computer and I try to build it in Android Studio I get an error saying this:

```
Error:(12) error: unknown element <resources> found.
Error:(12) unknown element <resources> found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

We use Android Studio and I am almost certain that the error is in the gradle, but I have tried everything and I can't get it to work. If you need more information I am happy to provide it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Comment: Just a line above the errors you pasted, there should be a path of the file that contains the 'unknown element'. Paste that file's contents so we can investigate. But it looks like a misformed XML structure - you probably pasted the <resources> element under an already existing <resources> element.

Comment: Actually, this failed during linking, which makes me believe you might have put the <resources> tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file (it does not belong there). Check your AndroidManifest.xml contents

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I checked AndroidManifest.xml and it is there. But, if I delete it, it just pastes itself back in. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean it lasted itself back in? Maybe you're trying to modify the merged manifest in the build directory. Check the one in the the myproject/app directory.