# Android : 9-Patch image Error

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

i imported this keyboard [app](https://github.com/soeminnminn/SulfurKeyboard) from git everything is working fine but i am getting this error while building project

```
Error:top-left corner pixel must be either opaque white or transparent.
Error:found an invalid color.
Error:top-left corner pixel must be either opaque white or transparent.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for detail
```

can anyone tell me what is the problem please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Comment: some time this is caused by long directory path.

Comment: @NoumanCh directory path mean? can you please tell me how to trace which image is causing this problem

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by an incorrect/corrupted 9-patch file. They should have a transparent or opaque white border, but yours doesn't seem to have it. Try following the steps in this: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: can you please tell me what is meant by border? top most pixels? please explain

Comment: there are so many images in android studio can you please tell me how can i check in which images is this error?

Comment: Just above this error there should be the path of the image. If it's not there, try running with the --debug flag and checking in the full log.