# i am creating a project and getting this trouble while running i have tried to cleaning the project relaunching it

Tags: android

```
03-19 14:57:58.523 22517-22517/com.example.vrindabhatt.wall_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vrindabhatt.wall_app, PID: 22517
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07007a
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2345)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:125)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:210)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:187)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:196)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:476)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1164)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:291)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1051)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1078)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:461)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:57)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your error message it seems that you were trying to get a drawable resource and Android can't find that resource. Possible solutions,

1. Make sure you have linked the resources using findViewById
2. Check that all the resources you are calling from your code are present in your drawable directory.
3. you can update your question and give us some more story as to what you were trying to achieve and maybe share the code snippet which you think might have caught the problem.