# Android studio 3.1 on Windows 10 aapt2 is missing 27.0.3 sdk

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1, aapt2

trying to develop a simple app for Android device.  Have installed android studio 3.1 on Windows 10 machine and trying to build "hello World" app.  keep getting error  = "Cause: aapt2 is missing on 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt2.exe'".  aapt2.exe is not in the 27.0.3 folder only aapt.exe.

What am I missing?  Shouldn't this just work ?

Comment: Looks like some sort of SDK path misconfiguration

Comment: Kindly check this link if this help you in any way  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988209/5952645

Comment: sommesh thanks for the link.  unfortunately, does not refer to my issue.  does anyone understand why 3.1 is looking for aapt2.exe in the Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\ folder, but it does not exist.  deleting the folder and letting 3.1 re-sync does not create aapt2.exe only aapt.exe

Comment: Further update. I uninstalled Studio 3.1 and cleaned all android related folders.  Then I installed old version 2.3.  It runs the hello world app without issue.  installed SDK build-tools 25.0.2 and 27.0.3 , and both now contain the aapt2.exe.  running     compileSdkVersion 25    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3".  Now I'm going to try and update the Studio version to 3.1

Comment: As soon as I went back to version 3.1 the issue resurfaced.  I'm sticking with version 2.,3

Answer (score 2):

The SDK manager sometimes messes up when downloading build tools. It's not necessary to re-install Android Studio - just delete the build tools folder/version that's missing the executable and re-download that.

Comment: Never imagined this would ever happen, but indeed it worked. Reinstalling the build tools brought in the missing aapt2 executable.

Answer (score 1):

Open `File > Project Structure` and select `app` under `Modules` category from left bar. Then select a higher `Build Tools Version` from properties tab. The error must be gone.

Answer (score 0):

In `gradle.properties` file put this line: `android.enableAapt2=false`

It worked with me