# Android Studio 3.1 creating a project with an instant error

Tags: java, android

Recently I installed Android Studio 3.1 to learn coding.

I installed "sdks, java and other things"

When I create a project it starts with and error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':base:mergeDebugFeatureResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
13 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

By the way in the design section there is nothing. It says " Design editor is unavailable until a successful build"

Comment: show your project level and app level build.gradle file.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail/47027653.

Comment: Post the whole build log containing the AAPT errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me. If anyone have the same problem just give it a shot.

Just simply change the .gradle folder from the settings.