# android studio build error appt2

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, build, project

the error is

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

the event log shows >>

```
18:31   Emulator: error: build_directory_structure: lstat: No such file or directory

18:31   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

18:31   Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

18:31   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

please help  I tried everything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Comment: Can you go to the Terminal window and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and post the output here? That will show us the logs with the details mentioned in the error message.