# I'm building an android apk of my ionic 3 application in android studio but getting this error "AAPT2 error: check logs for details"

Tags: android, ionic3, apk, aapt, aapt2

I am working with the latest version of android studio. i have been searching for the same from last two days got some solutions but would not worked for me.

Comment: Please check my answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail/46988596#46988596

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Comment: Did you check the logs for details?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska yes,  i have changed the following:    

| in buil.gradle 

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
    }
}



| in gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip


| Now i am getting this error
 "The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig in the build.gradle file."

Comment: @MobinAbbasi great :) now you should remove the minSdk version from the AndroidManifest.xml file.