# Error: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having problem with my android studio. I can't get it to work on my phone but the emulator is working. I keep getting:

> AAPT2 error: check logs for details

each time I try to run it on my android phone. Can someone please help me?

I'm still new to android studio and would appreciate any help I can get. I've attached a screen shot of the error page:
[image: Error page image]
 Thanks

Comment: show your logs please

Comment: show your log for better answer pls

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this link:
[Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)
I think this is due to sdkversion. As in the screenshot android studio not find the style of that version you are mentioned in the app build.gradle file.