# Android Studio 3.1.4 Cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1.4

I know there are many similar questions, but none of them fix my issue.

Firstly there is an error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`. Also in the build tab, there is an error: `Build: build failed`. Over to the side of that, it says `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`.

My program has two activities.

I have tried all the different things people said to try and they didn't work.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dennisranish.wificontroller">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Controller"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Settings"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In Merged Manifest tab:

```
Merging Errors: 
Error: Missing one of the key attributes 'action#name,category#name,data#scheme,data#host,data#mimeType,data#port,data#path,data#pathPattern,data#pathPrefix' on element intent-filter at AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-26:29 app main manifest (this file), line 24 
Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)
```

**Update:**

> Your Settings Activity declaration should look like this:
>
> ```
> <activity android:name=".Settings"
>     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>     android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
> ```

This does fix the *AndroidManifest.xml* error. However `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'` is still and issue and in the build tab, there still is an error: `Build: build failed`. **Except now over to the side of that, it now says `AAPT2 error: check logs for details`.**

Also some people said to post the error logs and I was wondering: When I click `Help > Show Log in Explorer` is it the right log; because there are 12 logs all contain over 1000 lines

Thanks for any help and if any other file is needed please let me know.

Comment: Post your log please

Comment: check your layout drawable folder

Comment: have you tried to `see logs` as it suggests?

Comment: Open a Manifest file,in bottom section there is tab Merged Manifest tap on it,it will show you error at right side

Comment: try to build and send build error

Comment: `.Controller ` is an activity or other class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: When I click Help>Show Log in Explorer is it the right log; because there are 12 logs all contain over 1000 lines

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Answer (score 4):

Your error message is pretty clear:

> Missing one of the key attributes
>   'action#name,category#name,data#scheme,data#host,data#mimeType,data#port,data#path,data#pathPattern,data#pathPrefix'
>   on element intent-filter at AndroidManifest.xml

Your Settings Activity has blank `intent-filter`, removing it will fix the issue.

> If `intent-filter` is added, it **must** contain `action` tag and
>   can/cannot contain `category` and `data` tag, [Reference Android
>   intent-filter doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element)

Your Settings Activity declaration should look like below:

```
    <activity android:name=".Settings"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Hope it helps!