# "AAPT2 error, failed parsing overlays" problem in Android studio

Tags: android, parsing, overlay

After updating Android Studio, I get this error when building project:

[image]

and this:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Comment: Can you go to the Terminal window and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and post the output here (make sure you include std err as well as std out)? Also could you list the files in app/build/intermediates?

Answer (score 4):

Try: `Build` -> `Rebuild project` .

Answer (score 2):

Update your android Gradle plugin version in your build.gradle file to 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer it all compiles fine:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle in text

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable AAPT2 by setting `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties`.

Or use `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'` or latest version.

More details: [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Comment: when i added "android.enableAapt2=false" in "gradle.properties" i get this error :
The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by deleting app/build folder and then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently changed your namespace 'com.yourcompany.yourappname' and your current import to your resources 'com.yourcompany.your_app_name.R' doesn't match would also cause this error.

Make sure your namespace matches your imports