# How to fix AAPT2 warning [The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: android.enableAapt2] in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.3

When I build my **App**. I got **Warning**, after update **Android Studio version** to **3.3** and update gadler plugin etc.

[image]

this is my **build.gradle(Module:App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jirin.kollinapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Post your gradle.properties file.

Comment: Remove android.enableAapt2=false from gradle.properties

Comment: Someone has asked this question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like AAPT2 is enabled by default with Gradle 3+.

Make sure to update to Gradle 3.3.0. Then do a clean.

The warning just tells you to remove `android.enableAapt2=false` from gradle.properties.