# The following project options are deprecated and have been removed:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

"The following project options are deprecated and have been removed" . I have add "android.enableAapt2=false" in gradle.properties but it could not resolve my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the following from **gradle.properties**

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

then syc grad

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is here, since you didn't pose one, but let me try answering.

You are getting a warning "The following project options are deprecated and have been removed" because you're trying to use a flag that has been removed. Remove "android.enableAapt2=false" from your gradle.properties and the warning will disappear.

If you're having issues with aapt2 you need to actually give the error from aapt so we can help. To see the messages from aapt2 you can usually scroll a bit above the error stacktrace in your build log and find messages starting with "aapt" or "error:".

Most of the time the errors mean that there's something wrong **in your project** so pay attention to them and try to use them to fix your project.